# Java: How to determine programmatically that a dataset doesn't follow a normal distribution?

Tags: java, algorithm, distribution

In a Java program, how can I determine if a dataset I have is following or not a normal distribution?

Is it possible?

Is there an API or an algorithm that I can use that determines this?

Comment: You're getting deep into statistics here, and the language matters hardly at all.  You will also have to decide what criterion you want to use, since there will be errors.  How do you want to classify datasets that are questionable?  Do you want to make sure you include almost all normal distributions, or that you reject almost all non-normal ones, or something in between?  What's your prior probability of a dataset representing a normal distribution?

Answer (score 5):

There are two questions here: how to determine if a [distribution is normal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test) and how to [do so in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/448643/statistical-library-for-java). As the first link will show you, there are varying degrees of how certain you want to be that you are looking at normal data from the formal to the informal. The second link shows that there aren't standard Java packages for statistical analysis but many other ways to implement them.

Answer (score 4):

This is a somewhat difficult statistical question and if you're not an expert in statistics, it seems deceptively simple.  Your goal apparently is to determine whether the data could plausibly have come from **any** normal distribution, not one with a pre-specified mean and variance.  Probably the best way to do this is with [D'Agostino test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D%27Agostino%27s_K-squared_test), which is based on measuring the [skewness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skewness) and [kurtosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kurtosis) of the distribution and comparing these to what's expected under normality.

As far as Java implementations, there are none that I'm aware of, although I don't regularly use Java.  I would be slightly surprised if there is one, as it's a relatively obscure statistical function and Java isn't the most common language to use for statistics.  However, [my D language implementation](http://dsource.org/projects/dstats/browser/trunk/tests.d) (search in this file for dAgostinoK()) could probably be trivially translated to Java if you already have functions for computing skewness, kurtosis and the CDF of the Chi-Square distribution.

Comment: @dsimcha: +1 damn, it's harder than what I thought.  I ll study these fine links.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if there's an API available for this, but what you can use is the chi-square test http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-square_test. Assuming your dataset is large enough, you can test for the fit to a normal distribution.

Comment: While you can use the chi square test, I would discourage it. The chi square test is best for categorical/discrete data. I would recommend one of the many tests devised specifically for normal distributions, as described by msw's link above.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is "If I have n > 30 data points, then it approximates a normal distribution via the central limit theorem." ;)

As others mention, determining if the data points *came* from a normal distribution is significantly more difficult.

Comment: I think what you mean is "if I have n > 30 independent and identically distributed data points then the random variable consisting of the sum of these points is approximately normally distributed". An arbitrary set of 30 points could be anything.